# MPMoviePlayerViewController memory problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

I have a problem with MPMoviePlayerViewController on iPad iOS 4.2. An application plays a video, but when the video stops the memory doesn't released.
To create a video player I use the following code:

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController * videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:articleUrl];
    [videoPlayer moviePlayer].movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [videoPlayer moviePlayer].controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [videoPlayer moviePlayer].scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [videoPlayer moviePlayer].fullscreen = NO;

    self.playerViewController = videoPlayer;
    [videoPlayer release];
    videoPlayer = nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];

    CGRect playerFrame = CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, self.view.frame.size.height - 40); 
    player.view.frame = playerFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];
```

and there is the movieFinishedCallback: method code:

```
    - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:player];
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player release];
    player = nil;

}
```

Can anybody help me with it? I have read a lot of topics related to this problem, but haven't found solution.

Comment: This won't answer your question but there's a bug in your code - the line that says `player release` should be `self.videoPlayerController = nil`. Otherwise, your releasing the player but keeping a pointer to it (very bad!)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good - your releases match your retains etc.

Have you run this in Instruments - i.e. is it definitely a leak? How do you know that the memory is not being freed?

There's nothing wrong with the video playback framework keeping your video cached as long as it releases the memory if you run short (i.e. get a low memory warning). Try running it in the simulator and simulating a memory warning - I bet that the memory gets released then.

Also, you don't know if it's going to be autoreleased at any point.

I wouldn't be worried about this problem until you run into memory warnings. Until then, I'd just assume the video framework knows what it's doing!

Comment: I have run Instruments. And if the video stops size of allocated memory doesn't decrease. I mean if the size of allocated memory during playing the video is 20 Mb that after video is finished the size of allocated memory is still 20 Mb.

Comment: That's still not necessarily a problem - if the app releases the memory when there's a low memory warning then it's fine. Try sending a memory warning in the simulator and seeing what happens.